# Rails 5 Friendly Way to Optimize Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like to simplify my approach to the following query.  (Using MySQL and Rails 5.0.1)

I have a Prospect with many Results.  I want to generate a list of last updated Results on all Prospects with results to use in my controller.

Prospect
    has_many :results

Result
    has_one :Prospect

This works in my Propects model

```
def self.last_results
  customer_ids=Result.where("results.disposition" => "appointment").where.not("results.event" => nil).distinct.pluck(:prospect_id)

  all=[]
  customer_ids.each { |c|
    last_result= self.includes(:prospect)
      .where("results.prospect_id" => c)
      .order("results.created_at ASC")
      .last
    all << last_result
  }
  return all
end
```

I think there must be an easier rails way to do this without creating multiple loops with queries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring working code are better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I was just looking at stackexchange and saw someone voting for moving a similar type question to stackoverflow because it might get better answers since it was rails specific. I need to know how to do this in a rails specific way.  I cobbled this together to explain the question better